# StringBuilder constructor implementation vulnerable to exception

Tags: java, stringbuilder

The initial capacity of a `StringBuilder` when initialized with an existing String or CharSequence is the length of the original `text + 16` from the  code in `StringBuilder` constructor:

```
super(str.length() + 16);
```

My query what if the original length is close to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` ?

Will it throw `NegativeArraySizeException`or will it change int to long for proper execution ?

Comment: why not just try it? and are String that long really needed?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger-- I tried and share my answer as well please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NegativeArraySizeException` is expected here as :

1. As per the `String` implementation, a `String` internally use a `char[]` to hold the individual characters. So the maximum String length is actually dependent on the `char[]` size .
2. Java internally use `int (not Integer)` to index the individual locations of an array and hence the maximum length of a `String` can be `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and any thing greater than that should throw an exception as `JVM` will not be able to index the individual locations which are more than maximum `int` value.

Due to this constraint `NegativeArraySizeException` is thrown for any array which expands beyond the max allowed limit which in this case is max int value.

Comment: Balbeer mere beer---aah tera account hai...(Y)

Answer (score 0):

It will throw a `NegativeArraySizeException` since the integer will have wrapped around.

Effectively, it's the same as:

```
int len = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

// here we are trying to create an array of size -2147483633
char [] value = new char[len + 16];
```

Answer (score 0):

it will throw NegativeArraySizeException